# Images not working in Google App Engine email

Tags: html, google-app-engine

I am trying to send an e-mail within my GAE project. The img tag is:

```
<img src="http://myapp.appspot.com/img/logo1.png" width="216" height="189" alt="logo">
```

When I manually navigate to the url, I see the image, but when I open the e-mail (sent to a gmail account), I get the broken image symbol.

Any idea on what I may be doing wrong? My gmail settings allow all images to display.

Comment: Which language are you using java/python/php? How are you sending the email? Put the code in question.

Comment: I'm using the Java Mail API.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have enabled the viewing of external images within the Gmail web app. (See: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/145919)

Also check the policy of the site that you are hosting the image on.  Some will specifically block an image from being fetched from the site when embedded in an email or such for many reasons:  copyright (make sure that you have permission to use the image), overload (ie using within an a email sent at a mass level), and so many more.

For example, when I tried to load the image URL that you specified in your message, I was given the following error:

[image: Life Log Error Message]